# 404 homepage on deployment

Tags: deployment, 404

I got a Craft-style 404 page when deployed to server. The homepage displays fine in local/development environment.

On the server, the admin interface works fine though.

Here's my config.

```
return array(
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
    'loginPath' => 'users/login',
    'logoutPath' => 'users/logout',
    'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true,
    'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
    'defaultFilePermissions' => 0664,
    'defaultFolderPermissions' => 0775,
    'devMode' => true,
);
```

Does anyone has a clue on how to debug this?

Will a mismatch in the license's domain name cause this?

Comment: An invalid license won't kill your frontend – only the CP (it will display a message prompting to transfer/purchase a license or downgrade). Have you double checked your template paths/that your templates exist on the server? Also, check logs under ```/craft/storage/runtime/logs``` – perhaps there'll be a clue in there.

Answer (score 3):

I was being silly here. We have separate folder for all frontend assets (including twig templates), which will be copied over to the craft folder on build. The target files are gitignored and need to be force add to git. I added the files under web but missed out on the craft/templates folder.